# C++ mysql order by is not ordered

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a little problem with my code.
Normally my code should display the players with the most kills.
It should look like this

```
user1 10
user3 9
user6 4
user10 1
user2 0
```

But it's just randomly sorted.

That's my code:

```
if (mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT Name, Kills FROM userdata ORDER BY (Kills) DESC LIMIT 0,10;")) 
{
    printf("ok");
}
MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(&mysql);

if (result == NULL) 
{
  printf("Result is null");
}
int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

MYSQL_ROW row;

int i;
num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
   unsigned long *lengths;
   lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
   for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
   {
       printf("%.*s", (int) lengths[i],
              row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf(" \n");
}
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: it seems to be `ORDER BY Kills DESC` to me.

Comment: @RichardHodges this doens't change anything

Comment: You misunderstand me. This SQL statement has asked for the results in descending order of Kills. That is exactly what you have. It's doing exactly what you have asked.

Comment: could it be that `Kills` is a `VARCHAR` and not an `INTEGER`? If so you'd get lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Always test your SQL statements using the MySQL console application.   This removes the need to debug your code when the SQL statement is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your code  seems that you want select  0 rows offset 10. Then try using limit 10 only for get the first 10 rows

```
SELECT Name, Kills FROM userdata ORDER BY Kills DESC LIMIT 10;
```

remove also the unuseful ()